# why sorl thumbnail cache folder is not created?

Tags: python, django, sorl-thumbnail

`sorl` - `thumbnail` image not displaying ...

after the long debug i found that cache folder is not created may be that's cause this issue ?

*settings.py*

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'sorl.thumbnail,
)

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

How to debug this ?

Comment: Does the user that runs the webserver have write permissions in the `media` folder?

Answer (score 1):

set in settings.py

```
THUMBNAIL_DEBUG = True
```

and see why it is not displaying.

you need to migrate `sorl.thumbnail`, so it will get its tables created, i think

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `'` at the end of `'sorl.thumbnail,` in `INSTALLED_APPS` in your `settings.py`.

Comment: Corrected. Thanks.